# How can I view Android source code in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I didn't see a good answer to this on here yet, but sorry if it's a duplicate. How can I see Android source code in Android Studio? I'd like to be able to look at the classes for View, CountDownTimer, etc.

Comment: Do u mean: select the type, right-click -> goto-> declaration ?

Comment: It's free to download. Google for it, download it, open it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a mac hold Command + click the object. I think it is Control + click on a windows machine.

Comment: That worked! I knew there was a shortcut I stumbled upon once but couldn't remember it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Select my answer please

Comment: I will. Can't for 5 more minutes.

Comment: how do you control which api level source code you can see ?

Answer (score 0):

Center Click(middle click) the mouse over the classes which you want to look